# Built exe using Cygwin on Win10, but getting errors regarding kernel32.dll

Tags: c++, linux, cygwin, kernel32, getaddrinfo

I'm new to Cygwin. I installed it today (latest release downloaded from their web site), and built a program I've been working on, one which, years ago, was built for Windows using Cygwin by a different developer - [Blitzed IRC Trivia](https://github.com/andy5995/blitzed-irc-trivia/tree/develop) (develop branch).

Under Win10/64, Cygwin finished a complete build with only the same 2 warnings (pertaining to Unused but set variables) that I receive when I make it on Linux. I've been developing and running it on Linux fine for a over a month. It connects to an IRC server and starts asking questions.

After I used Cygwin to make an exe, It would start, but fail the check when it got to [L25](https://github.com/andy5995/blitzed-irc-trivia/blob/02f41e9c233eaa5d5b4dbf431131ba98f9fbba30/src/client.cpp#L125) So it's breaking in the `connect_to` function (link above). I re-checked my code several times, and finally installed gdb from the Cygwin package manager.

When I ran it through gdb, before getting to the breakpoint, I received an error that looked pretty serious regarding kernel32.dll. Unfortunately I didn't paste the output to a file so can't produce the exact error without rebooting to Windows.

But after I run it in ReactOS (in a VirtualBox on Debian 8), after I put the cygwin dlls in place, I get a dialog box

> the procedure entry point CancelSynchronousIo could not be located in the dynamic link library kernel32.dll

I searched Google but haven't found anything concrete yet. My next step would be to try posting on the Cygwin mailing list.

Comment: ReactOS is still in alpha. What did you expect. They probably didn't implement `CancelSynchronousIo` function yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried building without using -static and it is working now. I don't know why that caused the error.